# Delegate Referencing to NULL

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a problem with delegates and that are referencing to `null`, I have this:

First I define the delegate which is going to act:

```
    public delegate void MandarComponente(int Componente);
    public event MandarComponente MandarComp;
```

As I want this to be in a drag-and-drop operation, I'm going to put some of the important stuff of the code of the drag + drop

```
        private void Capacitor_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) //This is a PictureBox Event
    {
        componente = 1;
        Capacitor.DoDragDrop(Capacitor.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

Once I have It, then I'm going to use it in the event

```
public void tableLayoutPanel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pl = new Point(this.Location.X + tableLayoutPanel2.Location.X + 10, this.Location.Y + tableLayoutPanel2.Location.Y + 32);
        int R = (int)((e.Y - pl.Y) / pictureBox1.Height);
        int C = (int)((e.X - pl.X) / pictureBox1.Width);
        Console.WriteLine("X=" + e.X + "Y=" + e.Y + " [" + C + ", " + R + "]");

        if (R == tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount) R--;
        if (C == tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount) C--;

        PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)tableLayoutPanel2.GetControlFromPosition(C, R);

        if (R == 0 && C == 0 || R == 2 && C == 0 || R == 2 && C == 2 || R == 0 && C == 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("¡No puedes poner un componente ahí!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            pictureBox = null;
        }


        if (componente == 1 && pictureBox != null)
        {
                pictureBox.Image = Capacitor.Image;
                MandarComp(componente);
                MandarComp = new MandarComponente(CambiarTexto);

                if (R == 1 && C == 2 || R == 1 && C == 0)
                {
                    pictureBox.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                }
        }
```

That is referencing this method:

```
    void CambiarTexto(int Componente)
    {
        if(Componente==1)
        {
            label5.Text = "Componente Seleccionado: CAPACITOR";
        }

    }
```

But the part of `MandarCom(Componente)` always has an exception of `NullReferenceException`.

Edit: Basically what I'm trying to do is that the delegate `MandarComponente(int Componente)` saves `componente` and then send it to the `CambiarTexto` method so It would do the action in `label5.Text`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "But the part of MandarCom(Componente) always Displays the exception of NullReferenceException" - then `MandarComp` is null. You haven't explained why you *expect* it to not be null. (It's also not clear why you're setting it in the line after invoking it - that's very unusual for an event.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm new at the event Handlers and delegates, so what I was trying to do was to create a Delegate which could send `componente` to the event `CambiarTexto` so a text from a label was changed

Comment: Okay, I think it's probably best if you read a tutorial on events and delegates then. Normally you'd want something *subscribing* to the event (and you wouldn't set it within your own class). `MandarComp(componente)` will invoke all the existing event subscribers - but you don't have any. I suggest you start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, Actually I just saw that delegates work for linking code that are external to the program; so basically I am using them wrong; but I couldn´t find a better way to do it so, was the first thing that came to my mind. But thanks Really, I´m going to watch tutorials abouts events and how to handle them!

Comment: If you just want to call `CambiarTexto`, just do it: `CambiarTexto(componente);`. That's all you need to make a method call. No need for delegates or events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using an event, before you invoking it, firstly you have to give it a value, which means the index of your assignemnt and invoking is wrong.
that should be:

```
MandarComp += CambiarTexto;//For event, += is used more offen than directly assignment.
MandarComp(Componente);
```

That should work.

Besides, if you are using the latest version of C#, it allows you to write like this `MandarComp?.Invoke()` to avoid a NullReferenceExcption.

Moreover, I also suggest you to start with some basic using of delegate and event.
If your delegate is just used in the owner class, that's kind of waste. Directly invoking of that method will do the same thing.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is a really odd use of events though. If the OP just wants to call a method within the same class, there's no point in using events. The purpose of events is to let *external* code subscribe to it, and there's no indication that that's happening at the moment. Yes, this answer will make the error go away - but without any improvement in terms of understanding events.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's right. I will edit the answer. Next time I will reconsider before postting the answer.